# Visual Studio 2019 - Changing Quick Action Order

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I recently updated Visual Studio Professional 2019 to 16.10.3. It appears that the order of the Quick Action refactoring suggestions has changed for C#. The Quick Action for "Create and assign property 'ParameterName'" used to be first. I developed some pretty strong muscle memory around this feature. After each parameter, I simply activated the Quick Action menu via the shortcut Alt+Enter, then immediately hit Enter again to complete the first action, which was "Create and assign property 'ParameterName'." The activation was very fast and easy, requiring just two key combinations (Alt+Enter, Enter).

After the update, it appears that "Add null check" is first in the list:

[image]

I now have to open the Quick Action menu via Alt+Enter, arrow down to the 'Create and assign' option and select it. Usually I also have to undo the null check I just inserted out of muscle memory.

Is there any way to specify the order in which the refactoring suggestions appear in the Quick Actions menu? I've searched MSDN and Settings in Visual Studio with no success.

Comment: Based on my search, it seems that there is no actual method to change the Quick Action Order. Maybe you could request a feature in the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home).

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT thanks for the comment. Please consider posting this as an answer since this appears to answer the question. I will not be submitting a feature request for this. All previous experiences on Developer Community have been extremely poor. It will be more productive to try to restore my computer to before the update.

Comment: I have  posted an answer. If don't mind, you can click '✔' to mark my reply as the answer, It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: I created a Developer Community feedback item if you want to upvote it.  In the past Microsoft has been pretty good about fixing things like this.

https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Order-of-quick-actions-changed/1492959?space=8&q=create+and+assign&sort=newest

Comment: @JeffPapp thanks for taking the time, I'll upvote. Unfortunately my experience has been the exact opposite, especially regarding bugs. Hopefully your good fortune continues and they do something about this.

Comment: @PatrickTucci, they created a Roslyn issue for this now if you want to drop your two cents in there.  Sounds like they are actively looking at it.  https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/55401

Comment: @JeffPapp thanks, I saw that. Your post has enough info. This is why I didn't create a Dev Community request in the first place. The Dev Community issue was closed as duplicate w/resolution. The "resolution" is a Github issue that was created minutes before the Dev Community issue was closed. So it was not a duplicate when entered. It's not resolved because the "resolution" is an unresolved Github issue. If Microsoft doesn't care about user feedback, that's fine. For me, they never have. But they shouldn't pretend to with theater like Dev Community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my search, it seems that there is no actual method to change the Quick Action Order.

Maybe you could request a feature in the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home).